# Aggreggate - map though object keys that values are arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

guys.

I can't figure it out how to map though object keys that values are arrays. I tried something with $map but that seems to iterate though array itself, which is not my case.

Document looks like this:

```
{     
    id: 1234,     
    name: 'Random',     
    subjects: {        
         math: [5,4,3],         
        biology: [3,3,3]     
    } 
}
```

I need to make query that return average of each subject, for above code should be mathAvg: 4, biologyAvg: 3

Desired output:

```
{     
    id: 1234,     
    name: 'Random',     
    subjects: {        
         math: [5,4,3],         
        biology: [3,3,3]     
    },
    mathAvg: 4,
    biology: 3

}
```

I figured out how to make for one subject, but cant iterate though subjects to make this operation for many.

For each subject:

```
db.students.aggregate([{$match: {id: 1234}}, {$addFields: {mathAvg:{$avg:`$subjects.math`}}}])
```

Comment: All the students have the same id ? ;)

Comment: of course not, its just example :), but I need that query for single student

Comment: That was a rhetorical question. In your aggregate, you match a specific id. So it can only return a specific id. If you have no dup, try to look for how to match every students instead of one based on its id.

Comment: but that is not my case/problem, query should work for specified id of student, and my question is not how to use query on all students, but how to iterate thought subjects to get avg for each subject

Comment: It does return the desired output https://mongoplayground.net/p/j-dvhl6LAiq ?

Comment: this is only for one subject (in this case math), biology should also have field biologyAvg, if there were more subjects like (math, english, biology) there should be 3 avg for each subject

Comment: You can add more fields. Something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/H2z8iwgM9EZ

Comment: I know, but this should be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ypImqrvjps0)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "subjectsAvg": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
          "input": { "$objectToArray": "$subjects" },
          "as": "a",
          "in": {
            "k": "$$a.k",
            "v": { "$avg": "$$a.v" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: It's something wrong with that query, I get error "errmsg": "Error: command failed: [\n\t\"ok\" : 0,\n\t\"errmsg\" : \"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'\",\n\t\"code\" : 16436\n] : aggregate failed,

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: 1.6.8 stable 2015-05-11

Comment: I check this solution on new version and it's work great. Isn't it possible to adpot this to 1.6.8 version ?

Comment: No you have to upgrade to 3.6 or above to make it worked

Answer (score 0):

Simpler pipeline with exact expected output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        '$project': {
            'name': 1, 
            'subjects': 1, 
            'mathAvg': {
                '$avg': '$subjects.math'
            }, 
            'biology': {
                '$avg': '$subjects.biology'
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: The problem is that this query is not elastics, if there were 100 subjects you will write same line over again for all of them ? This solution is good if there is few subjects and operation its one-time operation, above solution is elastic for subject number

Comment: Noted.  The key is to produce the "desired output" as described in the original question.